# return False if ... не работает

Tags: python, return

Имеется выражение:

```
return False if first_image.shape[0] and second_image.shape[0] != 604
```

после запуска программы выдает ошибку:

```
return False if first_image.shape[0] != 604
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Без сокращенного return'а все работает как надо.

В чем проблема?

Comment: По-моему, добавление секции с `else` решает проблему (синтаксис `a if condition else b` у Вас нарушен)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно `else` писать при этом выражении (`x if <условие> else y`), т.е.:

```
return False if first_image.shape[0] and second_image.shape[0] != 604 else True
```

Еще можно так (просто инвертируем результат):

```
return not (first_image.shape[0] and second_image.shape[0] != 604)
```